# How to append to a specific place in a file in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby

I am trying to create a webpage to be able to sell things online, and have come up with an issue while creating a file to automatically create a new item. I am trying to use Ruby to temporarily take off the end of the file, append the correct line to the file, and put the end back. My code so far is

```
puts "what is the item number?"
item_num = gets.chomp
puts "what is item description?(not optional)"
desc = gets.chomp

file_text = File.read("template.html")

file_text = file_text.gsub(/Item#/, "Item #{item_num.to_s}")
file_text = file_text.gsub(/<img class="item-image" src="">/, '<img class="item-image" src="' + item_num.to_s + '">')
file_text = file_text.gsub(/Item-desc/, desc)
puts file_text

file_create = File.new(item_num.to_s + ".html", "w")
file_create.puts(file_text)
file_create.close

item_page_end = '

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="headings">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer" style="width=80%"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/55b73bf748.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
'

file_to_update = File.read("item_page.html")
file_to_update = file_to_update.gsub(item_page_end, "")
file_to_update = File.open("item_page.html", "a+")
file_to_update.puts( '<p class="col-md-4"><img src="../images/' + item_num + '.jpg" />Item' + item_num + '</p>')
file_to_update.puts(item_page_end)
sleep 10
```

The HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>SHS Metal | Store</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/logo-icon.png"/>

        <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="../css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="../css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main element">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h2 class="title mt80">Store</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="headings">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer" style="width=80%"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/55b73bf748.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What ends up happening is that the program inserts the HTML line I want to add to the "item_page.html" file to the end and then adding the "item_page_end" string at the end. Does anyone know how to fix it put the HTML line in the Ruby program after

```
<h2 class="title mt80">Store</h2>
```

Any other solution I have found is either for an array, a string or simply doesn't work.

Comment: would that be easier than having 3 files?  `header.html`, `product.html`, `footer.html` where 1 & 3 are static and the second is what you generate?  The final output being a concatenation of those 3?

Comment: @Anthony Yes that would work actually. But how would you select everything in the main file Item_page.html to replace it with the concatenated 3 files?(I'm a very young programmer with little knowledge, please forgive me if I ask a dumb question)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your solution isn't very workable. Instead, it sounds like you need to step back and rethink the problem. Modifying existing HTML this way is error prone. A templating engine like HAML or ERB would make it easier, allowing you to programmatically insert content into the page as it's being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the HTML file, I see two possible answers:

(Please note that in all cases I use a function called `add_all_elements` which is a function that just returns whatever you want placed in your file.)

1. Cut your file in two, read the first half, add your elements and then read the second half. It should be something like this:

   ```
   buffer = File.read("template_first_half.html")
   buffer += add_all_elements()
   buffer += File.read("template_second_half.html")
   ```

   It is easy to use, but the HTML can be difficult to read.
2. You can also add a reference in the file and use gsub to replace it:

   ```
   buffer = File.read("template.html")
   buffer = buffer.gsub("#####anchor#####", add_all_elements())
   ```

   Also easier to use, it will require that you place a unique sub-string within the file.  The problem is that the reference must absolutely be unique within the file.  The advantage is that the HTML file remains easy to read.

If you cannot edit the HTML file:

```
line_num = 0
buffer = ''
break_point = 42
text.each_line do |line|
  if line_num == break_point
    buffer += add_all_elements()
  end
  buffer += line
  line_num += 1
end
```

Basically, you read the file line-by-line and place it into a buffer. When the line count reaches the required value (here, the variable `break_point` that I set at 42) you insert into the buffer all of the elements.

The inconvenient is that if the file is edited, the breaking point must be re-set each time. You could also use a string as a break point to avoid most of that problem.

Comment: This would work but what is the #####anchor##### that you use in 2? Does that select everything in the file?

Comment: no, this is just a special combination of characters that you add and you know is unique ( you do not want gsub to replace multiple times or replace the wrong one ).
it allows you to place the code you whant in the right place
I use this method here : [link](https://github.com/Hellfire01/MangaScrap/blob/master/templates/chapter_index_template.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
file_to_update = File.read("item_page.html")
file_to_update = file_to_update.sub(/(?<=<h2 class="title mt80">Store<\/h2>)/,file_text)
File.write("item_page.html",file_to_update)
```

With this there's no need to create a new file for file_text.
Basically whats happening is the second line here uses a lookbehind assertion to insert file_text into file_to_update after "Store</h2>". Then you just overwrite the contents of item_page.html with the updated string.